# SQL Server : select query timeout

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I am running a query that contains several joins and returns around 4K records on a SQL Server instance used for the QA environment. When I run the query on my local development machine and on the SQL Server instance used for the DEV environment through SSMS the query returns immediately (0 seconds), but when the same query is run on the QA environment SSMS query window it takes around 50 seconds to return. The query is generated from a .NET application using Entity Framework 6. The code used in the .NET app is the following:

```
var includes = new List<Expression<Func<TAM, object>>>();
includes.Add(t => t.AssetClassModels);
includes.Add(t => t.AssetClassModels.Select(acm => acm.Allocations));
includes.Add(t => t.AssetClassModels.Select(acm => acm.Allocations.Select(a => a.TAMAssetClass)));
includes.Add(t => t.AssetClassModels.Select(acm => acm.Allocations.Select(a => a.TAMAssetClass.BroadAssetClassType)));
includes.Add(t => t.AssetClassModels.Select(acm => acm.Allocations.Select(a => a.TAMAssetClass.Correlations)));
var tam = innerUnitOfWork.Repository<TAM>().Find(x => x.Id == tamResult.TAM.Id, includes);
```

The SQL query generated by the code above is the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project4].[Number] AS [Number], 
[Project4].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project4].[ProductTypeId] AS [ProductTypeId], 
[Project4].[GlidePathTypeId] AS [GlidePathTypeId], 
[Project4].[CashEquivalentPreferenceId] AS [CashEquivalentPreferenceId], 
[Project4].[TAMClientId] AS [TAMClientId], 
[Project4].[C3] AS [C1], 
[Project4].[Number1] AS [Number1], 
[Project4].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project4].[TAMId] AS [TAMId], 
[Project4].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project4].[Id3] AS [Id2], 
[Project4].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder], 
[Project4].[Id2] AS [Id3], 
[Project4].[TAMAssetClassId] AS [TAMAssetClassId], 
[Project4].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
[Project4].[ModelId] AS [ModelId], 
[Project4].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project4].[IsCore] AS [IsCore], 
[Project4].[ExpectedReturn] AS [ExpectedReturn], 
[Project4].[StandardDeviation] AS [StandardDeviation], 
[Project4].[BroadAssetClassTypeId] AS [BroadAssetClassTypeId], 
[Project4].[Id4] AS [Id4], 
[Project4].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
[Project4].[DisplayOrder1] AS [DisplayOrder1], 
[Project4].[C1] AS [C3], 
[Project4].[Id5] AS [Id5], 
[Project4].[TAMAssetClassXAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassXAxisId], 
[Project4].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassYAxisId], 
[Project4].[Correlation] AS [Correlation]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Project3].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Project3].[ProductTypeId] AS [ProductTypeId], 
    [Project3].[GlidePathTypeId] AS [GlidePathTypeId], 
    [Project3].[CashEquivalentPreferenceId] AS [CashEquivalentPreferenceId], 
    [Project3].[TAMClientId] AS [TAMClientId], 
    [Project3].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Project3].[Number1] AS [Number1], 
    [Project3].[TAMId] AS [TAMId], 
    [Project3].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
    [Project3].[TAMAssetClassId] AS [TAMAssetClassId], 
    [Project3].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
    [Project3].[ModelId] AS [ModelId], 
    [Project3].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder], 
    [Project3].[Id3] AS [Id3], 
    [Project3].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project3].[IsCore] AS [IsCore], 
    [Project3].[ExpectedReturn] AS [ExpectedReturn], 
    [Project3].[StandardDeviation] AS [StandardDeviation], 
    [Project3].[BroadAssetClassTypeId] AS [BroadAssetClassTypeId], 
    [Project3].[Id4] AS [Id4], 
    [Project3].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
    [Project3].[DisplayOrder1] AS [DisplayOrder1], 
    [Project3].[Id5] AS [Id5], 
    [Project3].[TAMAssetClassXAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassXAxisId], 
    [Project3].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassYAxisId], 
    [Project3].[Correlation] AS [Correlation], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project3].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Project3].[Id2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Project3].[Id5] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project3].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Project3].[Id2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project3].[Id1] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project2].[Number] AS [Number], 
        [Project2].[ProductTypeId] AS [ProductTypeId], 
        [Project2].[GlidePathTypeId] AS [GlidePathTypeId], 
        [Project2].[CashEquivalentPreferenceId] AS [CashEquivalentPreferenceId], 
        [Project2].[TAMClientId] AS [TAMClientId], 
        [Project2].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
        [Project2].[Number1] AS [Number1], 
        [Project2].[TAMId] AS [TAMId], 
        [Project2].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
        [Project2].[TAMAssetClassId] AS [TAMAssetClassId], 
        [Project2].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
        [Project2].[ModelId] AS [ModelId], 
        [Project2].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder], 
        [Project2].[Id3] AS [Id3], 
        [Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Project2].[IsCore] AS [IsCore], 
        [Project2].[ExpectedReturn] AS [ExpectedReturn], 
        [Project2].[StandardDeviation] AS [StandardDeviation], 
        [Project2].[BroadAssetClassTypeId] AS [BroadAssetClassTypeId], 
        [Project2].[Id4] AS [Id4], 
        [Project2].[Name1] AS [Name1], 
        [Project2].[DisplayOrder1] AS [DisplayOrder1], 
        [Project2].[Id5] AS [Id5], 
        [Project2].[TAMAssetClassXAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassXAxisId], 
        [Project2].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassYAxisId], 
        [Project2].[Correlation] AS [Correlation]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Limit1].[Number] AS [Number], 
            [Limit1].[ProductTypeId] AS [ProductTypeId], 
            [Limit1].[GlidePathTypeId] AS [GlidePathTypeId], 
            [Limit1].[CashEquivalentPreferenceId] AS [CashEquivalentPreferenceId], 
            [Limit1].[TAMClientId] AS [TAMClientId], 
            [Join4].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
            [Join4].[Number] AS [Number1], 
            [Join4].[TAMId] AS [TAMId], 
            [Join4].[Id2] AS [Id2], 
            [Join4].[TAMAssetClassId] AS [TAMAssetClassId], 
            [Join4].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], 
            [Join4].[ModelId] AS [ModelId], 
            [Join4].[DisplayOrder1] AS [DisplayOrder], 
            [Join4].[Id3] AS [Id3], 
            [Join4].[Name1] AS [Name], 
            [Join4].[IsCore] AS [IsCore], 
            [Join4].[ExpectedReturn] AS [ExpectedReturn], 
            [Join4].[StandardDeviation] AS [StandardDeviation], 
            [Join4].[BroadAssetClassTypeId] AS [BroadAssetClassTypeId], 
            [Join4].[Id4] AS [Id4], 
            [Join4].[Name2] AS [Name1], 
            [Join4].[DisplayOrder2] AS [DisplayOrder1], 
            [Join4].[Id5] AS [Id5], 
            [Join4].[TAMAssetClassXAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassXAxisId], 
            [Join4].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassYAxisId], 
            [Join4].[Correlation] AS [Correlation]
            FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) 
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Extent1].[Number] AS [Number], 
                [Extent1].[ProductTypeId] AS [ProductTypeId], 
                [Extent1].[GlidePathTypeId] AS [GlidePathTypeId], 
                [Extent1].[CashEquivalentPreferenceId] AS [CashEquivalentPreferenceId], 
                [Extent1].[TAMClientId] AS [TAMClientId]
                FROM [dbo].[TAM] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Limit1]
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent2].[Number] AS [Number], [Extent2].[TAMId] AS [TAMId], [Join3].[Id2], [Join3].[TAMAssetClassId], [Join3].[Percentage], [Join3].[ModelId], [Join3].[DisplayOrder1], [Join3].[Id3], [Join3].[Name1], [Join3].[IsCore], [Join3].[ExpectedReturn], [Join3].[StandardDeviation], [Join3].[BroadAssetClassTypeId], [Join3].[Id4], [Join3].[Name2], [Join3].[DisplayOrder2], [Join3].[Id5], [Join3].[TAMAssetClassXAxisId], [Join3].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId], [Join3].[Correlation]
                FROM  [dbo].[TAMAssetClassModel] AS [Extent2]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent3].[TAMAssetClassId] AS [TAMAssetClassId], [Extent3].[Percentage] AS [Percentage], [Extent3].[ModelId] AS [ModelId], [Extent3].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder1], [Extent4].[Id] AS [Id3], [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent4].[IsCore] AS [IsCore], [Extent4].[ExpectedReturn] AS [ExpectedReturn], [Extent4].[StandardDeviation] AS [StandardDeviation], [Extent4].[BroadAssetClassTypeId] AS [BroadAssetClassTypeId], [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id4], [Extent5].[Name] AS [Name2], [Extent5].[DisplayOrder] AS [DisplayOrder2], [Extent6].[Id] AS [Id5], [Extent6].[TAMAssetClassXAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassXAxisId], [Extent6].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId] AS [TAMAssetClassYAxisId], [Extent6].[Correlation] AS [Correlation]
                    FROM    [dbo].[TAMAssetClassAllocation] AS [Extent3]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TAMAssetClass] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[TAMAssetClassId] = [Extent4].[Id]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[BroadAssetClassType] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[BroadAssetClassTypeId] = [Extent5].[Id]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TAMAssetClassCorrelation] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent3].[TAMAssetClassId] = [Extent6].[TAMAssetClassYAxisId] ) AS [Join3] ON [Extent2].[Id] = [Join3].[ModelId] ) AS [Join4] ON [Limit1].[Id] = [Join4].[TAMId]
        )  AS [Project2]
    )  AS [Project3]
)  AS [Project4]
ORDER BY [Project4].[Id] ASC, [Project4].[C3] ASC, [Project4].[Id1] ASC, [Project4].[C2] ASC, [Project4].[Id3] ASC, [Project4].[Id2] ASC, [Project4].[Id4] ASC, [Project4].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier',@p__linq__0='63C18415-1101-47A9-9BDE-5950AAACA488'
```

What would be the more likely cause of the slowdown in execution on the QA environment when the database structure (tables) and data is the same across all local, DEV, and QA environment? How can I speed up the time it takes to execute this query? The indexes are the same on all three environments.

Comment: Have you checked (and possibly updated) your statistics on the QA server? Possibly these are out of sync, after a large data load or something like that...

Comment: what about the sql versions in the servers?
sessions arithabort settings?
have u check with recompilation?
then in the the end we would like to see both versions of execution plans for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check execution plans on both servers and most probably you will find QA server does not optimize the joins in its execution plan

If this is the case, you will need to run `update statistics` on QA server to optimize its execution plans

[Here is more info about Update Statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that tables and data and indexes are same in both environment. So the only reason I can think of is the statistics are not updated in the QA environment.  I have had this issue before too and updating the statistics solve it.

Comment: could you please explain the difference between your answer and mine that was post 2 hours before yours. If you agree with my answer, you better vote it up to support it instead of duplicating the answer.

Comment: I am a newbie on this forum so still understanding how things work here. Count this for rookie mistake. I tried to vote up your answer but it wouldn't let me saying I need 15 reputations to do that.